# Laravel doesn't read css and js files (nginx)

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

I am trying to make an app using laravel 7 and nginx on Docker for Windows.

I succeeded to show a top page on laravel in a public folder, but it never reads css and js files in the public folder and shows 404 errors.
The 404 error page is sometimes the one of nginx, and sometimes the one of laravel. (The code I will show you bellow shows the one of laravel)

I suspected this problem is related to my nginx configuration, and tried a lot of things but nothing works.

Here is my laravel's directory structure.

```
blog
-public
--index.php
--css
---index.css
--js
---jquery-3.4.1.min.js
```

Here is my nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$uri - $is_args - args :::'
                      '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Here is my default.conf. The codes commented out are things I tried.

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/blog/public;

    location / {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    #location ~ \.(css|js)$ {
    #    root /var/www/html/blog/public;
    #    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #}
    #location /css/ {
    #    alias /var/www/html/blog/public/css/;
    #}
    #location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    #    root   /var/www/html/laravel/public;
    #    expires max;
    #    add_header Cache-Control public;
    #    access_log off;
    #}
    #location ~ \.css {
     #   add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
    #}
    #location ~ \.js {
    #    add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
    #}

}
```

I've been stucked on this problem for two days, so any suggestions are helpful.

**Edit**:

That's what the access.log says:

```
172.24.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2020:10:36:09 +0000] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 443 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36"
172.24.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2020:10:36:10 +0000] "GET /js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1564 "http://localhost/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36"
172.24.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2020:10:36:10 +0000] "GET /css/index.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1564 "http://localhost/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36"
```

The error.log says nothng.

**20200401**

I changed the root of default.conf to /var/www/html and changed directory structure to figure out if this problem was the one of laravel or not. Following files works as a raw php app. The index.php tries to read index.css.

```
html
-index.php
-css
--index.css
```

It reads index.css  but does not change the style. I wrote same css as index.css onto  tag on index.php to make sure if syntax was correct, and it correctly changed style. Moreover, it showed following error on Chrome:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/index.css".
```

index.css is like this on my editor:

```
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
```

but on the browser, index.css is same as index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Sapphire test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/test.css">

</head>
<!--<style>-->
<!--    h1{-->
<!--        text-align: center;-->
<!--    }-->
<!--</style>-->
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Sapphire test</h1>
</header>
<main>
    <p>Hello World</p>
</main>
<script>
</script>
<footer>

</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

it's so confusing.

Comment: What is the entry in the access log and is there anything in the error log?

Comment: Thanks Richard. I added what  the access.log and error.log say in the question.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to check your entire configuration. From the information in your question, it should be working!

Comment: Yes, I did the syntax check  In summary, it says the syntax is ok and the test is successful. If it should be working, I might overlook some very basic things...  but I'm sure that the both css and js files exist in the public folder.

Comment: You either need to add;

`include /etc/nginx/mime.types;`

...or you're using two separate Docker containers, and you've not mounted the volume for the nginx container.  I feel like this is more likely, as I see you've a named container `fastcgi_pass php:9000;` this is fine for serving the PHP but your static assets need to be served as well.  Maybe post your docker-compose.yml file for pointers.